# Linux adobe flash player youtube videos sound distorted

Tags: sound, video, flash, youtube, adobe

When I just start my computer, youtube videos work fine. However, after working for some time (might be related to suspend session), youtube videos don't work good anymore. They are very non-fluent: the sound is distorted but it seems like the video itself is doing well.

I tried to install the new adobe flash version but this didn't help.
I tried to manually kill the adobe flash plugin, but this didn't help either.
What does help is rebooting my computer, but off course I don't want to do that again and again.

Has anyone got an idea why the sound is distorted? Or even better, has anyone got an idea how to fix the sound without a reboot?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How much RAM is there on your computer *(add the output of `free -h` from when the problem occurs)*, and what graphics/sound hardware are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could post this as a comment but apparently I don't have enough reputation.  In any event, it seems to me like there is a data bottleneck somewhere.  So, check to see that you have sufficient internet speeds for your video quality (try scaling it back from 1080p as most internet connections are too slow, and will cause a "pixel" image accompanied with distorted audio), or it could be the audio card on your motherboard is not compatible with the new flash player audio output.  However, the latter is less likely. If i was you, I would check my hardware to make sure the speed is sufficient for the video quality, and if you are using an older computer, try setting the video settings to the lowest possible quality.  Let me know if it helps at all.